# When I connect Postgres and reload the data in Qlik giving me error

Tags: qliksense

Qvx_Unexpected_end of data :sql###f-sql state :25p02,Error code:1,Errormsg:current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block;
Error while fetching next result.

When I tried to reload from Qliksense some time it’s working and some time not. Please suggest me on this.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: Any chance you can post the sql that is causing this issue?